# How to pass multiple facebook Ids in presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession using FBWebDialogs?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbwebdialogs

How to pass multiple facebook Ids in `presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession` using `FBWebDialogs`?

```
NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                   FACEBOOK_APP_ID, @"app_id",

                                   @"http://www.google.com", @"link",

                                   @"TestApp", @"name",

                                   @"I'm playing Guess This for iOS. Join my leaderboard!", @"message",

                                   @"Guess This is a social puzzle game, just match the pictures to a 

    word or 
    phrase.", @"caption",
                                    facebookID,@"to",nil];


[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:session//[FBSession activeSession]

                                                parameters:params1

                                                   handler:

          ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error){

          }];
```

Then how to pass multiple facebook Id's in facebookId String?

Comment: No you can pass one id at a time.

Comment: Is there another procedure to pass multiple facebook id's ? Its my requirement any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add more than 1 `id` while using the `Feed Dialog` or `Send Dialog`

Comment: Is there is any other way to post messages in multiple facebook friends wall, or by tagging?

Comment: You can do tagging with Open Graph Actions, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/ . Else, you'll have to invoke dialog for each of the friend separately

Comment: What"s the open graph API?

Comment: I've mentioned the link in the prev comment. Pl check

Comment: Can you please specify URL-> facebook.com/me/... and also parameters dict?

Comment: Everything is in that link. What can you not find?

Comment: its api is showing "/me/cookbook:eat?" , and thanks for your valuable time

Comment: See its not straight-forward at all. Start reading from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph step-by-step

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing them in as a single string separated by commas.

If you have an array of id strings, you can do it like this:

```
[idArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]
```

**EDIT**

According to the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog), it does appear that for feed dialogs you can only have one user in `to`. What I said above does work for some dialog types though.

Comment: Its showing like "This dialog has been passed bad parameter".